# Better alternatives to the phrases "feel cold" and "feel hot"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The phrase "feel cold" doesn't sound correct to me. I am trying to describe "cold" as a general entity,  like "sadness" is to "sad". So what word should I use for "cold" and "hot"? "coldness" and "warmth" are not good alternative as they have wrong interpretation after the word "feel", as "warmth" is a feeling used by many to describe softness or love or some other feeling, But I mean the word "warmth" literally (to the feeling of hot or cold environment) what words should I choose in this case?

> Our climate is monitored 24/7, so you won’t have to ever feel cold or hot never again.

Does this sound logical? Maybe I am wrong and this is okay, but to me, it just doesn't sound right.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 'feel cold', and coldness and warmth can be either figurative or literal.  _Chill_ is a possible alternative.

Comment: @KateBunting I will provide the sentence itself: "our claimant is monitored 24/7, so you won’t have to ever fill cold or hot never again." Does this sound logical? maybe I am wrong  and this is okay, but to me, its just doesn't sound right.

Comment: Do you mean _our climate is monitored_? I would suggest 'you won't have to feel too cold or too hot ever again'.

Comment: You do hear "Feel the cold!", "Just feel that heat!", but they're rather emotive statements. You want something more clinical, even if it does sound a little prosaic. Go with @Kate's suggestion.

Comment: *Feeling cold* and *feeling hot* (or *feel the cold* or *feel the heat*) is the most natural (idiomatic) way of expressing the situation in English.